# I have ERC-1155 tokens I was airdropped in my Gnosis-Safe and I want to take them out? How can I do that?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have ERC-1155 tokens I was airdropped in my Gnosis-Safe and I want to take them out as they do not show as collectibles. They do appear on the Opensea API but not in GNOSIS-Safe so I cannot interact with them.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: ERC-1155 tokens aren't supported yet, but it's in the short-term roadmap.

Answer (score 2):

**SECURITY RISK**:

You should not do this unless you review the transfer code of the spam ERC-1155 contract. Just because it is named transfer, it does not mean the code will transfer the funds. The transfer function could do something nefarious - like approve the spending of your funds in addition to or instead of transferring the funds.

**Answer**

Assuming you have reviewed the contract and are confident the transfer function will perform what you expect, then...

You can submit a transaction to your gnosis safe to call transfer on the ERC-1155 contract to send them from your wallet to another. Here are some steps to follow: [gnosis transaction buider guide](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4680071-transaction-builder)

Also a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/B1D3TtxhoFA):